# User is getting logged out if one tab is closed in Vue

Tags: vuejs2, local-storage, vue-router

I am using localstorage to check and trace if user is logged in or not. At a time of login I am storing a token to local storage and validate in router/index.js.

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
 if (to.meta.requireAuth) {
   const token = localStorage.getItem('Token') || ''
   const sessionToken = sessionStorage.getItem('Token') || ''

   if (token || sessionToken) {
    return next()
   } else {
    next({path: '/login'})
   }
 } else next()
})
```

I need two features: One, if user logs in and then opens a new tab/window then doesn't need to log in again. I used local storage for this feature.
Now Second, if user closes all the tab or window which is opened then user should be logged out.
The issue is: I am clearing local storage on a beforeunload event. But if user has opened two or more tabs, this event logs user out from each tab.

Comment: sessionStorage is unique to each tab.  if the token is cleared from sessionStorage in tab 1, it should still persist in tab 2 unless you somehow sync the multiple sessionStorages together.

Comment: Agree. But if I use session storage won't it make the user log in to each new tab? @yoduh

Comment: could utilize localStorage to sync the login data between multiple storageSessions, but leave logout event unsynced.  something like what this [guide](https://blog.guya.net/2015/06/12/sharing-sessionstorage-between-tabs-for-secure-multi-tab-authentication/) explains